# i cannot be resolved to a variable

Tags: java, eclipse

My Plugin is spokeing a Error:

> Description   Resource    Path    Location    Type
>   i cannot be resolved to a variable  CommandMotdEdit.java    /MotdChange/src/com/xdisteer/plugin line 76 Java Problem

Code

```
  if (args[0].equalsIgnoreCase("remove")) {
      if (sender.hasPermission("motdedit.remove")) {
          if (args.length >= 2) {
            if (check(args[1]))
           {
              try {
                           i = Integer.parseInt(args[1]); //ERROR!!!
              } catch (Exception e) { int i;
                return true; }
                int i;
           if (i > MotdEdit.motdlist.size() - 1) {
                sender.sendMessage("§cMotd with ID '" + i + "§c' does not exist!");
                return true;
              }
              String motd = (String)MotdEdit.motdlist.get(i);
               Functions.removeMotd(sender, args[1], motd, label);
              return true;
             }
```

Comment: Can you put a comment on line 76 so we know which line it is?

Comment: declare variable i before using it

Comment: Have you defined or declared i somewhere ?

Comment: how i can declare variable i?

Comment: Just do `int i;` at the beginning of your methods or outside your methods.

Answer (score 0):

```
try {
                           i = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
              } catch (Exception e) { int i;
                return true; }
                int i;
```

Buggy code

because you are using i before it has been declared .

`i = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);` you need to declare i before this line of code

Comment: how i can declare this line?

Comment: Similarly the way you declare variable

Answer (score 0):

Change this line `i = Integer.parseInt(args[1]); //ERROR!!!`

to this:

```
Integer i = Integer.parseInt(args[1]); //ERROR!!!
```

and remove the `int i;` line